# How do I clear a stale pypi package from Heroku/Cedar's virtualenv?

Tags: python, heroku, virtualenv, pypi, cedar

I am building my own `flask-oauth` in my app's src/lib and adding it to the web application's path via: `sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd() + '/src/lib/flask-oauth')`  I have to do this because the pypi package doesn't have support for access_token_params, which google requires.

`flask-oauth` does not appear in `requirements.txt` currently, but it did in the past. As a result, it remains in my heroku app's vitualenv and I cannot get rid of it. My app works locally, but on heroku it dies with:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'access_token_params'
```

I have tried listing the latest github version of flask-oauth in my `requirements.txt` file as in: `git+git://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-oauth.git`, and the package does install. However, the application still loads the stale version from `/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flaskext/oauth.py` and the app still dies.

I have this in my requirements.txt:

```
-e git://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-oauth.git@80167c44abc3df37e43a45474d19452065430464#egg=Flask_OAuth-dev
```

And the correct, latest, github version of flask-oauth now installs locally and works. But I still can't get heroku to acknowledge or use that package in the app. It uses their old version in `/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flaskext/oauth.py`

How can I clear heroku's virtualenv of this stale package? How can I make it use the github version and not its cached package?

Note: I have created a new app called mythin-dev, and it reads my requirements.txt and installs the correct version of flask-oauth from

```
-e git://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-oauth.git@80167c44abc3df37e43a45474d19452065430464#egg=Flask_OAuth
```

So it seems that the problem is definitely the cached packages in my heroku virtualenv. Help, my application will not run on heroku until this is resolved :(

Answer (score 3):

Install this (https://github.com/lstoll/heroku-repo) Plugin and run `heroku repo:purge_cache -a appname`.